# How do I set the chapter in table of contents like this? (The comparison of what I get and what I want are in the code)

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, chapters

```
   \documentclass[twoside]{book}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{BAB}        
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{        

{\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
\if@mainmatter
\center \MakeUppercase{\normalsize\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter}

\par\nobreak
\vskip 6\p@ 
\fi
\fi
\interlinepenalty\@M
\normalsize \uppercase{\bfseries #1\par\nobreak} 
\vskip 30\p@ 
}}
%

\makeatother                        
\usepackage{titlesec}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{DAFTAR ISI}
   \makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
  \null\hfill\textbf{\normalsize\contentsname}\hfill\null\par
  \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}%
  \vspace{30pt}
  \@starttoc{toc}%
}
\makeatother
\usepackage{titletoc}% 
\titlecontents{chapter}% <section-type>
  [0pt]% <left>
  {}% <above-code>
  {\bfseries\chaptername \thecontentslabel \qquad}% <numbered-entry-format>
  {\bfseries}% <numberless-entry-format>
  {\bfseries\hfill\contentspage}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

I want to make the chapter like this\\
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\textbf{BAB I} & \textbf{PPPP}\\
\textbf{BAB II} & \textbf{PPPP}\\
\textbf{BAB III} & \textbf{PPPP}\\
\textbf{BAB IV} & \textbf{PPPP}\\
\textbf{BAB V} & \textbf{PPPP}\\
\end{tabular}
\chapter{PPPP}
\chapter{PPPP}
\chapter{PPPP}
\chapter{PPPP}
\chapter{PPPP}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is this related to your previous question? If so please explain the difference. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/519317/134144

Comment: it's same. I think some people will understand this questions and some will understand the previous questions. So, if you understand and you know the answer, please answer it

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  Your question is very unclear.  Please include a minimal working example (yours here is quite large and unlikely to be really minimal) and tell us not only what you want, but what's actually happening.

Comment: @dgoodmaniii just run the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome!
 It's easy with the `eqparbox` package:

```
 \documentclass[twoside]{book}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{BAB}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{

{\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
\if@mainmatter
\center \MakeUppercase{\normalsize\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter}

\par\nobreak
\vskip 6\p@
\fi
\fi
\interlinepenalty\@M
\normalsize \uppercase{\bfseries #1\par\nobreak}
\vskip 30\p@
}}
%

\makeatother
\usepackage{titlesec}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{DAFTAR ISI}
 \makeatletter
 \renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
 \null\hfill\textbf{\normalsize\contentsname}\hfill\null\par
 \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}%
 \vspace{30pt}
 \@starttoc{toc}%
 }
\makeatother

\usepackage{eqparbox}

\usepackage{titletoc}%
\titlecontents{chapter}% <section-type>
  [0pt]% <left>
  {\bfseries}% <above-code>
  {\eqmakebox[TC][l]{\chaptername~\thecontentslabel }\qquad}% <numbered-entry-format>
  {}% <numberless-entry-format>
  {\hfill\contentspage}[\vspace{0.5ex}]

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{PPPP}
\chapter{PPPPF}
\chapter{PPPPFF}
\chapter{PPPPFFF}
\chapter{PPPPFFFF}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much. How about set the lenght last section to next chapter in table of content? I want to make the space between sections are 12pt and the space last section to next chapter are 24pt.

Comment: I'll try to a way to do it later (I don't have time at the moment). The general idea would be to add some vertical space via the second mandatory argument of \titleformat (‘ above code’), but how much depends on the base font size of the document.

Comment: thank you. I'll add question for my account. Hope another can see and solve it. But if you have time later, please answer my question.

Comment: B.t.w., what should be the horizontal alignment of sections in the toc, with respect to chapters?

Comment: the section is parallel to the first word of the chapter title

Comment: this is my questions [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/519574/how-to-change-the-space-after-the-last-section-to-next-chapter-in-table-of-conte)